# Apart from Unity, what are the other alternative desktop manager for Ubuntu 18.04 providing fluid animation experience?

Tags: 18.04, unity, gnome

I have been using Ubuntu for the past few years. More specifically, I was using the Unity desktop environment for approx 6 yrs (Ubuntu 16.04, 14.04,...) and just recently did I make the switch to Ubuntu 18.04. Using Gnome desktop manager, my experience has not been on par and it just does not seem fluid (in regards to switching windows, animation, memory usage, etc)
My question is, what are the other alternative or [MAJOR] gnome tweaks that provide an on-par experience or better compared to Unity?

[*Please NOTE: An option of using the Unity manual does seem viable but the objective is to seek and taste other desktop manager experience. Also, using dconf, gnome tweak could fairly improve the experience but with lots of plugins and memory burden*]

Comment: Couldn’t you just keep unity or are you wanting to try something else?

Comment: @TheBuntuNewb Yes, I am looking for an alternative. Using Unity would solve the sluggish problem or make the experience richer but the question is for alternative 'Apart from Unity and gnome'. -Thanks

Comment: Honestly I would try KDE Plasma. It is the most customizable desktop environment I’ve ever used. The only drawbacks are that it uses qt instead of gtk and it can be slow at times. But you usually can find qt based themes easily